# Powershell Exchange Add-MailboxPermission

Tags: powershell, permissions, exchange, mailbox

The command Add-MailboxPermission is not working. It is giving me the error:

```
Cannot find information about the local server server.domain.com in Active Directory. This may be related to a change in the server name.
```

However, Get-MailboxPermission and some other commands (e.g. Get-Mailbox) from exchange Powershell module are working.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What the version of your exchange server? Can you assign permission via ECP?

Here are some suggestions for your reference:

1. Restart the server and check if this issue continues.
2. Drop the domain and re-join the server and check results.
3. Run the command : Dcdiag on DC server and post out the result.
4. Run command: repadmin /syncall /force to force DC replication.
5. Change another admin account to log on and run Add-MailboxPermission
   to check if this issue continues.